# Is there a way to click a button and have 2 different responses appear?

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a guessing the number game except when the number is too high or too low, the label can have more than one possible answer appear.  Ex: If the guess is 35 and the label says ("Too High") then guessing 36 and the label says ("That number is way too high!")

abz = the integer value for the number the user is supposed to guess
dys = the integer value for the number the user inputs as a guess (shown as a textbox)

```
    If dys < abz Then Label1.Text = ("Too Low!!")
    If Label1.Text = ("Too Low!!") Then Label1.Location = New Point(45, 187)
    If dys < abz Then lablab.Text = ("Guess Higher Then That!!")
    If Label1.Text = ("Guess Higher Then That!!") Then Label1.Location = New Point(34, 187)
    If dys > abz Then Label1.Text = ("Too High!!")
    If Label1.Text = ("Too High!!") Then Label1.Location = New Point(66, 187)
    If dys > abz Then Label1.Text = ("Guess Lower Than That!!")
    If Label1.Text = ("Guess Lower Than That!!") Then Label1.Location = New Point(98, 187)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't surround your string literals with parentheses like that.  It'll work that way, but it's meaningless, unnecessary, and non-standard.  Also, don't do the same check multiple times.  Once you check a condition with an `If` statement, you can do as many commands as you want in response to that condition.  You aren't limited to just one command per `If` statement.  If also seems odd that you're moving the label around based on the text you are putting in it.  I suspect, if you look, you'll find that the label control has some layout features which will cause it to automatically size or center based on it's content, so you don't have to do that manually.

Anyway, to answer your question, you could do what you want with an `Else If`:

```
If dys > abz + 10 Then 
    Label1.Text = "That number is way too high!"
    Label1.Location = New Point(45, 187)
Else If dys > abz Then 
    Label1.Text = "Too High"
    Label1.Location = New Point(66, 187)
End If
```

Comment: Shouldn't string literals always be surrounded with quotes?

Comment: pretty sure Parenthesis was what was meant.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Ah.. Now I get it.  Oops. :)